# QFieldCloud Synced to QGIS but data points are not showing

Tags: qfield, qfieldsync, qfield-cloud

I have created a project as I normally do in QGIS 3.32.1 and uploaded to the cloud. Data collected in the field is points. The changes were pushed, and I synced them in QGIS. However, none of the data points or attached information is present. I can see all the information and points in the cloud and on the phone but they did not transfer. The project says the sync has been successful and no further action is required.

I have uninstalled and reinstalled the plugin. I have checked that the associated folders are correct and checked the properties behind the layers but cannot find a solution. As a workaround I have pulled the points off Qfieldcloud website but dont want this to be a long term solution for the employees who dont normally have access to this side of Qfield.